# Как взять из таблицы те message-и id которых больше lasMessageID?

Tags: php, mysql

у меня в базе данных таблица, в котором есть id и message. Как взять из таблицы те message-и id которых больше lasMessageID, где lasMessageID id одного сообшения типа так или не знаю
SELECT message FROM messages WHERE id > lasMessageID

Comment: Блин, не уважаю тех кто, минусуют и не отвечают

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не ставь себе проблему, добавь в таблицу столбик time и поставь тип timestamp и будут выбирается последние сообщения

Comment: у меня и этот столбик есть, но дело в том что мне все равно нужно показать сообщения типа последние с помощю ajax каждые 30 секунд